# Unable to instantiate UIStoryboard(name: "something", bundle: nil)

Tags: swift3, crash, xcode8, uistoryboard

I'm getting a fatal runtime crash every time I attempt to instantiate a UIStoryboard. 
 Here is the screen shot of the result of a Exception Break:

[image]

[image]

However I *don't get a runtime crash* if I merely instantiate the UIStoryboard class with: **UIStoryboard()**; without any parameters.

I placed this code within the VC's ViewDidLoad() for a test and I still get the runtime crash.

What would cause such this fatal crash, everytime?

---

Here's the code:

```
 open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let myBundle = Bundle.main

        UIStoryboard(name: "Hamburger", bundle:myBundle)
      //   let storyboard: UIStoryboard? = UIStoryboard(name: "Hamburger", bundle: nil)

        if viewDidAppearFirstTime {
            viewDidAppearFirstTime = false
            configureAttributesViewer()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you try to use   UIStoryboard(name: "Hamburger", bundle:myBundle) this line?

Comment: UIStoryboard(...) was crashing.   I'm not interested in the result, merely to see if UIStoryboard will run without crash.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sample one that what you want and it works perfectly when I run the app also it does not show any error.Kindly find the below steps.

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let Hamburger = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Hamburger")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Hamburger, animated:true)
```

Comment: If 'Hamburger' VC is within the 'Main' storyboard, then the runtime works.  However if either 'Main' doesn't exist or the VC doesn't exist, it bombs.  I'm expanding this for my project as a possible remedy.

Comment: The bottom line here, is that the 'storyboard' must exist, otherwise a crash.   My problem, is that I do have the storyboard but apparently it isn't recognized.   Perhaps xcode is checking a framework vs a local; and doesn't find the storyboard.  I think the problem is Xcode's search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: wrong bundle name was used.
Storyboard was located in a different bundle.